# Container directive with padding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Depending on the directive "navigation" people use, the page content needs to have a certain padding.

This is done by the "content" directive, here called "container".

The padding or margin applied to the container seems to have render problems when an element is inside the container. But no problem when only text.

I made 2 snippets, exactly the same code except the div inside.
The 2nd snippet don't have a left padding

```js
angular.module('app', [])


.directive('container', function(){
    
  return {
     restrict : 'E',
     link : function(scope, element){
        
       element.css('border', '1px solid red');
       element.css('padding', '100px');
       
     }
  };
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  
  <container>
    test
    </container>
  </div>
```

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.directive('container', function(){

return {
  
  restrict : 'E',
  link : function(scope, element){
  
    element.css('border', '1px solid red');
    element.css('padding', '100px');
  
  }
  
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  
  <container>
    <div>TEST </div>
  </container>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Its because `div` is block element and nested within an inline element. Apply `display: block` to `container` element, the result will look same for both

Comment: Is their a way to choose the display (block, inline) within the directive?

Comment: No, there isn't. You can add class `element.addClass('displayBlockClass')` within your directive or hard-code rule `container {display: block}` to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add css:

```
container{
  display: block;
}
```

Otherwise, set the padding/margin to the inner div inside the directive:

```js
angular.module('app', [])


.directive('container', function(){
    
  return {
     restrict : 'E',
     link : function(scope, element){
        
       element.children().css('border', '1px solid red');
       element.children().css('padding', '100px');
       
     }
  };
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  
  <container>
    <div>
      test
      </div>
    </container>
  </div>
```